# Is the % for upvalue in Lua 5.x deleted

Tags: lua, closures

I'm learning Lua from a book, which is a bit old.
I've tried searching the web, but because of the use of the `#` sign in my search I get really confusing results.

It says that in order to use upvalue you need to use the `%` sign.

But when I write it in my code I get an error.

```
Account.new = function (starting_balance)
  local self = {}
  local balance = starting_balance

  self.withdraw = function (v)
    %balance = %balance - v;
  end
  return self
end
```

error is : `unexpected symbol near '%'`

Is there a new way to handle upvalues in Lua 5.x ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Lua 5.0, there is no more such thing as a "upvalue sign". An upvalue is a local to the environment a function is declared in, and as such can simply be accessed as any other local variable.

In your case: just use `balance` instead of `%balance`.

From Lua 5.1, `%` is used as modulo operator.

A good but slightly outdated book is the online available version of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/), and of course, the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html).

Answer (score 3):

Must be a very old book!
The `%` as upvalue notation was removed in Lua 5.0. (Released 2003)

Since 5.0, Lua has lexical scoping; 
that is, upvalues are automatic:

```
do
    local balance = 0
    function deposit ( v )
        balance = balance + v
        return balance
    end
end
print ( deposit ( 5 ) )
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the closure http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html#closures